# Chrome process model within WPF app?

Tags: .net, wpf, google-chrome

I'm wondering whether I could implement a Chrome style proces model with a WPF host. One process would handle the tabbing etc, and the content of each tab would be its own process. Maybe wpf or maybe winforms.

Comment: I've had some success using the User32 SetParent call.  Windows knows to route messages to the child window correctly.  However, if the GUI thread of a child process blocks, the whole composite application locks up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Win32 SetParent seems to be an easy solution, but it turns out that when a child process hangs, the parent will also hang as soon as you move the mouse over the child owned window.  I guess the SendMessage call in the host is synchronous.  I don't know how to go about fixing this.

So I'm going with a different approach - overlaying tabs over the top of existing windows.

Comment: Could you please post a bit more details on your approach? I would like to use a similar approach, but I cannot understand how to do it from your answer.

Comment: @Wilbert start a new question for that

Comment: ok: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230843/chrome-process-model-with-tabs-in-wpf-as-overlays